# Is there a macro recorder in Aptana?

Tags: aptana

I recently changed my editor from Net-beans to Aptana , it is quite a good editor but i miss a small feature in Aptana Studio and i could not find it , it is the macro recorder, is there one in Aptana or i have to live without?